# Neo4j how to match subpath

Tags: neo4j

Assumed that i have 2 trees in the graph:

```
(:TreeA)-->({caption:'b1'})-->({caption:'c1'})-->({caption:'d1'})
        +->({caption:'b2'})-->({caption:'c2'})
        +->({caption:'b3'})
        +->({caption:'b4'})-->({caption:'c4'})-->({caption:'d4'})
                           |                  +->({caption:'d5'})
                           +->({caption:'c6'})
                           +->({caption:'c7'})-->({caption:'d7'})

(:TreeB)-->({caption:'b4'})-->({caption:'c4'})
```

Is there any way to compare if `TreeB` is a subpath of `TreeA`?

Thank much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isomorphism problems are tricky, but since we're working with trees we can cheat a bit.

If we can match on all paths from root to end node, and produce a textual representation of those paths by extracting and joining the node captions, and we do that for both :TreeA and :TreeB, then we can check that for all of :TreeB's path representations, that they occur (form the prefix) of at least one of :TreeA's path representations.

```
// first get text representation of paths from :TreeA
MATCH p = (:TreeA)-[*]->(end)
WHERE NOT (end)-->()
WITH [node in tail(nodes(p)) | node.caption] as captionPath
WITH reduce(path='', caption in captionPath | path + ',' + caption) as pathText
WITH collect(pathText) as aPaths

// then get text representation of paths from :TreeB
MATCH p = (:TreeB)-[*]->(end)
WHERE NOT (end)-->()
WITH aPaths, [node in tail(nodes(p)) | node.caption] as captionPath
WITH aPaths, reduce(path='', caption in captionPath | path + ',' + caption) as pathText
WITH aPaths, collect(pathText) as bPaths

// ensure all text representations of :TreeB occur in at least one of the paths from :TreeA
RETURN all(path in bPaths WHERE any(aPath in aPaths WHERE aPath STARTS WITH path))
```

Note that if you're using APOC Procedures, you can replace usage of the reduce function:

`reduce(path='', caption in captionPath | path + ',' + caption) as pathText`

with the join() function:

`apoc.text.join(captionPath, ',') as pathText`