# How to (Efficiently) Find Subpaths in Recursive Trees through Cypher (Graph vs Regex)

Tags: recursion, graph, neo4j, tree, cypher

I'm trying to reproduce a Go SGF game tree in Neo4j through Cypher so I can pattern-search through, as a graph. This is the shape of a Go game tree — based on [Sabaki's SGF Parser](https://github.com/SabakiHQ/sgf) —:

```js
type GameTree = {
  id: number;
  data: { [key: string]: string[] };
  parentId: number | null;
  children: GameTree[];
};
```

> You can find a reproducible sample of the problem [in this commit](https://github.com/psygo/go_pattern_search/tree/01a11ff85b85e226b2f222aa4743e87842649651).

So far, I've successfully managed to model it just like it appears in a Go editor's game tree:

[image: Game Tree on Neo4j Desktop]

> `B` and `W` mean Black and White moves. `AB` and `AW` are "added black or white stones", for when editing the board position. For this question's purposes, only `move` matters actually, which has the same value as either `B` or `W`. Board coordinates are given in 2 letters, e.g. column `m` and row `r` gives out the string `'rm'`.

Now, what I would like to do is return the full path (probably the root node would suffice actually) from the root if a specified subpath (no skipping) is found. So far, I have this, which does work:

```
MATCH p=(g:GameNode)-[:NEXT_MOVE*]->()

WITH g, p,
     [m in TAIL(NODES(p)) | m.move] AS moves

WITH g, p,
     REDUCE(path = '', move in moves | path + move) AS joined_moves

WHERE joined_moves CONTAINS "rmro"

RETURN g, p, joined_moves
```

Following @cybersam's answer, I think this could make it more explicit to Neo4j so it uses an index on `m.move` — e.g. `CREATE INDEX move_node_move_idx FOR (m:MoveNode) ON (m.move)` —:

```
MATCH p=(g:GameNode)-[:NEXT_MOVE*]->(m1:MoveNode)-[:NEXT_MOVE*]->()

WHERE m1.move = HEAD(['rm', 'ro'])

WITH g, p,
     [m in TAIL(NODES(p)) | m.move] AS moves

WITH g, p,
     REDUCE(path = '', move in moves | path + move) AS joined_moves

WHERE joined_moves CONTAINS "rmro"

RETURN g, p, joined_moves
```

But I really don't know if this type of pattern-search would be efficient enough through Neo4j or other graph databases. I think it could be since, even though most games have 200+ move branches, there aren't that many of them usually. And the analysis would be on unidirectional branches where order matters (no skipping), so it should probably limit the search space even more.

Alternatively, I'm considering placing a string with the full path to it in each move node. This way I could use Regexes (I know Regexes can also be modeled as graphs) instead of path searches. That said, if it works, then I think using a SQL database would be probably enough. However, I would probably stick to Neo4j still, cause modeling this as a graph could provide more useful features in the future.

---

### References

- [Stack Overflow - *Neo4j how to match subpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51872011/4756173)
- [Stack Overlflow - *Efficient way of matching a subtree, using cypher in Neo4J?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31587455/4756173)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below should be fairly performant in returning the moves in every game that contains the desired sequence of moves. It assumes you:

- Have an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `MoveNode.move`,
- Pass the list of desired moves in the `$moves` parameter,
- Adjust the length of the variable-length relationship in the first `MATCH` to be 1 less than the length of `$moves`. For example, if `$moves` has 2 items, use `*1` instead of `*2`. *This is admittedly ugly, but Cypher does not support dynamic bounds.*

##### Query

```
MATCH p1=(m1:MoveNode)-[:NEXT_MOVE*2]->(m2)
WHERE m1.move = HEAD($moves) AND [m IN TAIL(NODES(p1)) | m.move] = TAIL($moves)
MATCH p2 = (m2)-[:NEXT_MOVE*0..]->(end) WHERE NOT (end)-[:NEXT_MOVE]->()
MATCH p3 = (g:GameNode)-[:NEXT_MOVE*]->(m1)
RETURN [a IN NODES(p3)[1..-1] | a.move] + $moves + [b IN NODES(p2)[1..] | b.move]
```

The index is used to limit and anchor the search by quickly finding the `m1` nodes (the `MoveNode`s matching the first item in `$moves`), instead of wading through all paths from every `GameNode`. Then the query:

- Filters `m1` by requiring that it is followed by a subpath satisfying the rest of the `$moves` list,
- Finds the sequence of moves that follow each subpath,
- Works backwards from the surviving `m1` nodes to find the corresponding `GameNode`s.
- Constructs and returns the sequence of moves for each matching game.

So, this query starts off by using the index to find the first set of relevant nodes, and keeps adding relationships (and end nodes) to what was already found until it finally has the desired results. There is never a need to scan through irrelevant data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @cybersam. Indeed, I think this much more explictly tackles the issue of using an index. Do you think my solution with `REDUCE` would have Neo4j unable to use an index on `m.move` (much like many SQL DBMSs)?

Comment: Also, could you include the specific index on `move` you mentioned? Is it something like: `CREATE INDEX move_node_move_idx FOR (m:MoveNode) ON (m.move)`?

Comment: And did you manage to get the reproducible example working? I'm trying your example on Neo4j Desktop by replacing `$moves` with `['rm', 'ro']` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: (I've added your index idea to my question's code.)

Comment: You can use `PROFILE` to see if indexing is used, and to see the number of db hits. The index creation statement looks fine. I tested my query on my own test data, so there may be differences with your actual data. Did you change the bound, as indicated in my 3rd bullet?

Comment: The first 2 lines do seem to work to return `p1`, but adding the rest of the 4 lines doesn't give me back anything, even if return `p1` again. I used `['rm', 'ro']` with `-[:NEXT_MOVE*1]->`.

Comment: I just fixed my `p2` statement to allow `m2` to be the same node as `end`. That might have been why it did not work for you.

Comment: I think it's working now!

Comment: If you're interested, I have a [follow-up question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77508656/4756173).

Answer (score 1):

To get the path `p` from the root `GameNode` up to and including the sequence of moves `['rm','ro']`, you can write the following in Neo4j 5.9+:

```sql
MATCH p = (g:GameNode)-[:NEXT_MOVE]->+(m1:MoveNode)-[:NEXT_MOVE]->(m2:MoveNode)
WHERE m1.move = 'rm' AND m2.move = 'ro'
RETURN p
```

To get the whole path, up to the last move in the sequence, you need to add a check that there are no further moves:

```sql
MATCH p = (g:GameNode)-[:NEXT_MOVE]->+(m1:MoveNode)-[:NEXT_MOVE]->
  (m2:MoveNode)-[:NEXT_MOVE]->*(lastMove:MoveNode)
WHERE m1.move = 'rm' AND m2.move = 'ro'
  AND NOT EXISTS { (lastMove)-[:NEXT_MOVE]->(:MoveNode) }
RETURN p
```

It would be surprising if there were performance issues: specific enough patterns over small graphs representing each game should not be slow.

Comment: The problem is that the specified subpath might have arbitrary length, so I don't think the `WHERE ... AND` solution is gonna be programmatic enough.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on the `->+` operator? I didn't know that existed. Is that equivalent or close to `-[:NEXT_MOVE*]->`?

Comment: The second query was missing the variable length tail. I've added that. I believe that addresses your comment that it wouldn't match subpaths of arbitrary length.

Comment: `-[:NEXT_MOVE]->+` is from new [quantified path pattern syntax](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/reference/#quantified-relationships). This particular pattern is the same as `-[:NEXT_MOVE*]->`.

Comment: ... and `-[:NEXT_MOVE]->*` is the same as `-[:NEXT_MOVE*0..]->` in old syntax. It's now equal to a Kleene star, as with regular expressions.

Comment: But how would you deal with the fact that the subpath is of arbitrary length? I mean it could be `['rm']`, it could be `['rm', 'ro']`, or `['rm', 'ro', 'pq']`, etc.

Comment: I assumed from your example that you were after paths that contained the sub-sequnce `rm` then `ro`, with no intermediate nodes. So the second pattern will match `['rm', 'ro']` as well as `['rm', 'ro', 'pq']` (or `['pq', 'rm', 'ro']` for that matter). But not `['rm']`. Am I missing something?

Comment: `rmro` was just an example of subpath. `rmropq` would have to find branches with `rm`, `ro`, and `pq` in that order for example (no combinations of subpaths within that subpath necessary). What I mean by variable lenght is that `rmropq` is length 3, while your solution is kinda hardcoded for length 2. That's why I couldn't get around using list comprehension and `REDUCE` in my solution.