# Practical Way of Doing Equality Against Multiple Possible Values in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

> This question follows up on [@cybersam's answer to one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77499034/4756173), however no previous knowledge about this problem is necessary.

In a pattern-search query, a simplified version of [@cybersam's query here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77499034/4756173), I would like to, ideally, match paths not only to an input pattern but to all of its isomorphisms (board rotations and reflections) and permutations.

> A pattern in this case is a list of strings (A-Z) of length 2, e.g. `['pq', 'dd', 'pp']`.

So, in that query, I would have to create an `OR` statement for each pattern in a pattern list:

```
MATCH p =   (mFirst:MoveNode)
           -[:NEXT_MOVE*${patternLength - 1}]
          ->(:MoveNode)

WHERE (
            mFirst.move = HEAD($patterns[0]) 
        AND [m IN NODES(p) | m.move] = $patterns[0]
      )
   OR (
            mFirst.move = HEAD($patterns[1]) 
        AND [m IN NODES(p) | m.move] = $patterns[1]
      )
   OR (...)
   .
   .
   .
```

Is there a way of making this programmatic? Cause, this isn't scalable, since I don't know how many permutations I'm gonna end up having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `ANY` predicate

```
MATCH p =(mFirst:MoveNode)-[:NEXT_MOVE*${patternLength - 1}]->(:MoveNode)
WHERE ANY(
  x IN $patterns 
  WHERE ( mFirst.move = head(x) AND [m IN nodes(p) | m.move] = x )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know `ANY` worked with list comprehension in this way!